# XMPP asmack: Contact presence not working for transitions to "available"

Tags: xmpp, asmack

I am using asmack 8-0.8.3.

I don't receive messages for changes of Presence from my contacts when they move to "available".
If one contact passes from "available" to "dnd", I do receive a message. But not in the other way around.

```
Contact passes: "available" --> "dnd" --> "available" --> "dnd"
I receive:                  Presence{dnd}             Presence{dnd}
```

Whereas I expect to receive a Presence update {available} between the 2 dnd.

Since I receive presence updates except for "available" I suppose my listener works fine. Also I suppose I correctly subscribed to my contacts' presence...

```
  private class FriendListener implements RosterListener {

    public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) { }
    public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) { }
    public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) { }

    public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
      String fromUserID = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(presence.getFrom());
      System.out.println(
        "Presence changed: " + fromUserID + 
        " Presence=" + presence.toString() + 
        " Type=" + presence.getType().toString() + 
        " Mode=" + presence.getMode().toString()
      );
      mainCallback_.updatePresenceFriend(fromUserID, presence);
    }
  }

public void subscribe(String friendID, String friendName) {
  Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
  connection.sendPacket(presence);

  RosterPacket rosterPacket = new RosterPacket();
  rosterPacket.setType(IQ.Type.SET);
  Item item = new Item(friendID, friendName);
  item.setItemType(RosterPacket.ItemType.both);
  rosterPacket.addRosterItem(item);

  connection.sendPacket(rosterPacket);
  System.out.println("Send subscribe to " + friendID);

  subscribedUsers.add(friendID);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem!

Actually there was a bug in the log of my Listener, this line:

```
    System.out.println(
    "Presence changed: " + fromUserID + 
    " Presence=" + presence.toString() + 
    " Type=" + presence.getType().toString() + 
    " Mode=" + presence.getMode().toString()
  );
```

It made crashed when Presence.getMode()==null, so that I did not process the Presence message. But no coredump was showing in the logs, I guess because the listener is in another thread...
Changing the log by the following line solved the problem

```
  System.out.println(
    "Presence changed: " + fromUserID + 
    " Presence=" + presence.toString()
  );
```